# How to convert unsigned byte array to base64 string in ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have an image buffer returned from a C SDK,

I can write to a local image and read it as `base64` string but this requires an extra step.

How can I turn the byte array into a base64 string directly so that I can send it in a network request?

```
image = (ctypes.c_ubyte*s.dwDataLen)()
ctypes.memmove(image, s.pBuffer, s.dwDataLen)
```

I tried using `base64.encodestring` but got this error

```
TypeError: expected single byte elements, not '<B' from c_ubyte_Array_8716
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 and base64 encoding of a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944806/python-3-and-base64-encoding-of-a-binary-file)

Comment: Have a look at [base64.encodebytes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes)

Comment: Which part of the answer worked for your problem?

Comment: What is the type of `s.pBuffer`?  There may be a way to eliminate the extra copy to another buffer type.

Comment: @DavidCullen Second part of your answer, the one with `base64.b64encode`

Comment: @MarkTolonenIt is a `byte` pointer. I declare it as `c_void_p` in my struct definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import ctypes
import base64

image = (ctypes.c_ubyte * s.dwDataLen)()
ctypes.memmove(image, s.pBuffer, s.dwDataLen)
# Convert the image to an array of bytes
buffer = bytearray(image)
encoded = base64.encodebytes(buffer)
```

If you are using `base64.b64encode`, you should be able to pass `image` to it:

```
import ctypes
import base64

image = (ctypes.c_ubyte * s.dwDataLen)()
ctypes.memmove(image, s.pBuffer, s.dwDataLen)
encoded = base64.b64encode(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `base64` module

```
import base64

with open("yourfile.ext", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

the case is similar with [Encoding an image file with base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715493/encoding-an-image-file-with-base64)

Comment: This would requires an extra write and read operation. Is there a method where a direct conversion from bytes to b64 string?